# IF function when true send a value of another cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create if function that If the condition is met then the result value will be taken from another cell?

I'm trying to wrap my head on it but can't figure it out.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0):

For Sure You know how if Condition Works :

```
  =IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

And for what you want to achieve :

> =IF(E1>200,f50*10) // if E1 is true then the value of E1 would be the value of f50*10 (or any other cell)

If you have any **Else** then :

> =IF(E1>200,f50*10,f51*10) // if E1 is true then the value of E1 would be the value of f50*10 (or any other cell) else it would be f51

Comment: You appear to only have two parameters for `IF` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

try simple reference:

```
=IF(A20=B20; C20; D20)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: i exactly answered this just without any photo :)